# Android podcast client with device sync and web management?

Tags: android, media-manager, podcast

I am looking for a better solution to listening to podcasts than the hodgepodge I have now. Unfortunately there seems to be a dizzying array of options but no clear leaders to evaluate.

I use Inoreader for RSS feed management and really like its feature set and workflow. I have no intention of changing this out for another tool so I'm looking for something that compliments it. While it supports podcast subscription and listening from the web interface, the mobile clients don't support audio media.

Minimally I want to...

- subscribe to and manage podcasts from the web.
- listen to podcasts from my Android phone and tablet.
- have read states for all feeds synced across devices.
- pre-load media while on WiFi so I don't use mobile data for huge downloads.

Ideally I would also like to...

- set a sleep timer to halt playback if no input received during a predefined period.
- to add one-off media links that are not feeds to my listen queue.
- not contend with a bunch of superfolous features.
- integrate with Inoreader so I can manage subsriptions from one place.

I'm willing to spend a few dollars for the Android client side of things if a really good solution exists. I tried Podcast Republic but feed management was a nightmare and it doesn't sync states between devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a combination of the excellent open-source podcast manager [AntennaPod](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.danoeh.antennapod) and the [gpodder.net](https://gpodder.net/) service.

> gpodder.net is a libre web service that allows you to manage your
>   podcast subscriptions and discover new content. If you use multiple
>   devices, you can synchronize subscriptions and your listening
>   progress.

It works with several client applications, **desktop** or **mobile**, or as a standalone **web** application without any client app. As said, I use it with AntennaPod, but the compatibility is vast, even though you might not get all the features with certain clients. Here is a list of [gpodder.net-compatible podcast clients](http://wiki.gpodder.org/wiki/Web_Services/Clients).

Comment: This combo looks great! I've already configured it all with my feeds, manually synced up my status and uninstalled all my other podcatcher software. An open source client and libre service was more than I was hoping for; and both seem to be quite well behaved.

Comment: I do quite like this solution.  But is there a way of creating playlists, or directing the client to download from the web browser?

Answer (score 1):

### [Pocket Casts](http://www.shiftyjelly.com/android/pocketcasts)

I also use InoReader for all kinds of feeds, along with Pocket Casts for podcasts. Pocket Casts is an elegant podcast manager with device sync and web management. It allows you to:

- [Subscribe to and manage podcasts from the web](https://play.pocketcasts.com/), for a single payment ($9 + tax that varies by country). Offers a 14 day trial
- Listen to podcasts across devices (2.99€ on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.shiftyjelly.pocketcasts))
- Saves and syncs **read** and **progress** states across devices. You can start playing a podcast on the web and continue on your device from where you left off
- Preload media on Wi-Fi using customizable rules for each podcast (download all, download latest only, ...)

Additionally:

- Has a custom sleep timer
- No superfluous features

Unfortunately, it does not integrate with InoReader.

---

I'm not sure re `one-off media links`. Could you please post a comment with one and I'll test it and update the answer