# Podcast application for Android and Windows

Tags: windows, android, web-apps, windows-7, podcast

I am looking for a podcast app that makes it easy to listen and manage all my podcast subscriptions across my desktop and android. So if I subscribe on one app, it will show up on my desptop (I guess though a web portal).

Also ideally it would keep track of my listened to episodes. So if I listen on on my desktop, the android app would reflect that.

Comment: Have you seen this thread here https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19996/android-podcast-client-with-device-sync-and-web-management?noredirect=1&lq=1? They talk about a "combination of the excellent open-source podcast manager AntennaPod and the gpodder.net service". Check it out. If not, have you considered registering for a SoundCloud account and downloading the Soundcloud app for Android?